# What does "leverage" mean in this sentence?

Tags: banking

"The biggest problem is that Deutsche Bank has too much leverage," noted analysts from Berenberg bank.

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2016/07/27/news/companies/deutsche-bank-profit-slump/index.html

Comment: the answer to the possible duplicate should explain all.

Comment: took me scarily long to find the duplicate only to find that the reason I knew it existed was that I wrote the answer!